# Failed to create an Android PHP MySQL Login app

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I'm creating a `Android` `PHP` `MySQL` Login app that will check the username and password from MySQL server. I get the tutorial from [here](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-php-mysql-login-tutorial-android-login-app-3/)

I have checked the name and password in `MySQL` and it matches with what user type, but I still unable to go to **HomePage** activity as it displays **Invalid username or password.**

```
 private void login(final String username, final String password) {

        class LoginAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

            private Dialog loadingDialog;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loadingDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Please wait", "Loading...");
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                InputStream is = null;
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
                String result = null;

                try{
                    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(
                            "http://192.168.1.7:80/Android/CRUD/login.php");
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                    is = entity.getContent();

                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    result = sb.toString();
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return result;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result){
                String s = result.trim();
                loadingDialog.dismiss();
                if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("success")){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomePage.class);
                    //intent.putExtra(USER_NAME, username);
                    finish();
                    startActivity(intent);
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid User Name or Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }

        LoginAsync la = new LoginAsync();
        la.execute(username, password);

    }
```

**login.php**

```
<? php
require_once("dbConnect.php");

$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);

$username = $_POST['name'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$sql = "select * from users where name='$username' and password='$password'";

$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$check = mysqli_fetch_array($res);

if(isset($check)){
echo 'success';
}else{
echo 'failure';
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: use json encoding because in your code may be return some invalid character

Comment: @Rasel How to encode ?

Comment: try to use fiddler2 to capture the HTTP request to analyse

Comment: you should study json encode first in php and get encoded data in android then decode it.http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: @XinMeng can you help?

Comment: @Rasel why the tutorial no need encode ?

Comment: are you using Emulator or Real mobile? if you use real mobile you can read [this article](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/ConfigureForAndroid). After you finish configuration, you can see all the package pass through you mobile. Then you test you app(such as pressing the login button), the mobile device will send a http request to your server, and the fiddler2 can capture it. Then you can analyse this HTTP request (Request part and Response part).

Comment: @XinMeng I use real device

Comment: I am not very familiar with PHP, through analyzing the package, you can know the problem occurred on Server side or Client side.

Comment: If you get the http request package, maybe you can add it to your question. I think it can give more information for you issue and let more people to help you easier.

Comment: encoding needed because the problem is you php i think.if you encode it it  you can prevent such type of result

Comment: I have found another [tutorial](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql/) , and it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
$username = $_POST['name'];
```

change to this one :

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
```

Answer (score 0):

check response in Log first..

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            String s = result.trim();
            Log.d("response: ", s);
        }
```

Comment: It display all my php

Comment: so problem is in your php

Comment: If you are using localhost+emulator use url... http://10.0.2.2:8080/      or json encode your response

Comment: @AshutoshVerma what should I do ?

Comment: @Hoo first use  HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(
                            "http://10.0.2.2:8080/Android/CRUD/login.php"), if it's not working json encode your response.